# Write a Dataframe as Parquet file in S3 Bucket with DuckDB-Python API

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, duckdb

I have a DuckDB Dataframe with 5 GB of Data, I would like to write the same to S3 Bucket as Parquet file, I see DuckDB Commands, but not able to find the python API for the same, any help he is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's the `duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation.write_parquet` method, as [documented in the Python API reference](http://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/reference/#duckdb.DuckDBPyRelation.write_parquet).

Note that you'll need to use and configure the HTTPFS extension for writing for S3. I'm assuming that Python `write_parquet` method plays nicely with the S3 writing support, but have not tried myself. It it turns out it doesn't you can always fall back to doing it with the SQL API directly using `duckdb.sql()`.